# Overriding type hint for an attribute of a class from 3rd party library

Tags: python, python-typing, pyright

I have a 3rd-party web-framework which has type hints in some of its code. I can not control the code of the said framework

Suppose I have following piece

```
from framework import web
...


class UserPosts(web.WebView):
    async def get(self):
        user_id = await self.request.user_dict['id']
        ...
```

`web.WebView` class has type hints in its code and `request` attribute is marked as an instance of a specific class which doesn't have `user_dict` attr in definition because it is a dict that my custom made middleware dynamically attaches to the request instance.

I want to provide type hint for `user_dict` but I don't understand how this can be approached.

Can someone help me with a tip about the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide some more code, enough to create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I am not sure that I can post it there as minimal example would require to create about 20 files and upload the 3rd party framework somewhere on the Internet

Answer (score 0):

Define a new class,
and override the ctor within that class:

```
class MyWebView(web.WebView):

    def __init__(self, ...):
        super().__init__( ... )
```

So far nothing has changed.

Now adjust the constructor so it uses proper type hints,
add logging and parameter validation to taste,
the world is your oyster!

Comment: Well, this might be the way to go but I doubt I can convince to touch code of 500+ files just to make pyright/mypy work well. I guess it would be easier to just abandon the idea of using typechecker :-(

Anyway, thanks a lot for your prompt response

Comment: Oh, you have many classes to worry about. Well, you can always write a source code parser. https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html Take a look at how folks produce type hint stub files for large code bases -- in some ways your problem sounds similar to that, which is a pretty well understood task at this point.

Comment: Is there maybe an opportunity to monkey patch the 3rd-party library at the proper moment? That is, after importing it but prior to the type hint analysis?